# UISegmentedControl tintColor/disappear bug in IOS 7.1

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, tintcolor

I set the tint color through `[UISegmentedControl appearance]` in AppDelegate.m:`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and see no problems initially. After an alert view is shown on any screen, tint colors of all `UISegmentedControl` instances are reset (to `clearColor` or `whiteColor`, didn't need to check) application-wide. They just disappear.

This is the alert view I use:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sialertview

Setting the tint color in `viewDidLoad` like below didn't change anything, although I can see in debug that the application hits this line.

```
[self.segmentedControl setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

The only solution I could come up with is this, which also runs in `viewDidLoad`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [segmentedControl.subviews count]; i++)
{
    [[segmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    for (int j = 0; j < [((UIView*)[segmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i]).subviews count]; j++)
    {
        [[((UIView*)[segmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i]).subviews objectAtIndex:j] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
```

The outer loop is for labels, and the inner one is for separators.

Any other/better ideas, please? Thank you...

Comment: come on, nothing at all..? :)

Comment: I have the similar problem on iOS8.1 and your solution works like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in AppDelegate

```
self.window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```

Comment: we switched the project to a whole new user interface, so i still didn't have the chance to try this. i will provide feedback as soon as i check it out.